# Bitwise operators in Postgres

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I have a problem with using Bitwise operators in Postgres I get the following error message

```
ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
```

My query looks as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT number,name,contact,special FROM clients WHERE special & 2048;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You'll need to do a comparison:

```
SELECT DISTINCT number, ..., special FROM clients WHERE special & 2048 = 2048;
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT number, ..., special FROM clients WHERE special & 2048 > 0;
```

Comment: Just in case the (signed) literal is negative, comparing `<> 0` might be a safer bet.